# Stretching text horizontally using CSS

Tags: html, css, text

I am required to stretch text horizontally, but the only thing I could find was [font-stretch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font-stretch) which, according to w3schools, isn't supported by any browser.

Is there any other way which I can meet this effect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Css, Can I stretch text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351013/css-can-i-stretch-text)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Yes** - you can achieve this by using **[CSS 2D transforms](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp)**.

Here's a working **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NTrqY/)**.

**Note** that the example in the Fiddle/code below is for Chrome/Safari (WebKit), however, you can use 2D transforms in all major browsers by using the `-moz-`, `-o-`, and `ms` equivalent prefixes/methods!

**HTML:**

```
<span>Hello!</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
span {    
  transform:scale(3,1); 
  -webkit-transform:scale(3,1);
  display:inline-block; 
}
```

**Support:**

It is supported in Chrome, Firefox, IE9+ and Opera browsers.

Comment: I would have done that already but I'm waiting for the timer to count down.

Comment: The `moz` prefix is firefox specific, and firefox auto updates, so no need there. And, the `-ms-transform` prefix was only needed on pre-releases of IE9, so no need for support there.

Comment: It seems the `display:inline-block` is mandatory, without it `transform` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this? With CSS:

```
text-align: justify
```