# Font Awesome: how to only increase the width of an icon?

Tags: font-awesome

I would like to only increase the width of the following icon:

```
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
```

I don't want to use things such as the following:

```
<i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-bars fa-3x"></i>
```

because the icons also increases in height.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12065925/87399) suggests using 2D transforms to stretch fonts; you could give that a try.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your input. I read the post you mentioned. 2D transformation sounds overcomplex for such a seemingly simple need. Besides, IE9+ might be an issue. Again, thanks!!!