# css: setting the proportion of font icons (other then font size)

Tags: css, font-face

We use custom icon font (inhouse font generated to icons with icomoon, or something similiar) in our webapp. I can set their size with `font-size` css property. but sometimes I need to adjust more proprties: for example increase the width or the height of the icon/font etc. Is there a way to do this with css/js?

I'll be glad for help with this, generating a specific font for each mini used isn't a path I would like to choose

Comment: What do you need to adjust the height / width for?  I mean, are you referring to the container, or the actual icon itself.  If it's the icon, why isn't `font-size` working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

font-stretch was supposed to do that but is not included in any current css standard and not supported by any browsers. I think you will have to create seperate icons for that case, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I did a Google Search trying to find the appropriate css descriptors, and stumbled upon this thread. Maybe it may help: [Is it possible to change the font height, not just the line-height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942995/is-it-possible-to-change-the-font-height-not-just-the-line-height)