# Unexpected space on top and bottom of div

Tags: html, css

This is my problem in short: https://jsfiddle.net/b6wLwkfs/

Long story: I have a div with some text in it. It initially creates some space on top and bottom of my div (this is not padding). I would like my div to only cover the text and not create extra space. This is my only css:

```
div {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px
}

<div>This is the text</div>
```

What I am looking for is to narrow down the div to only contains the text without creating any space on top of bottom. I acknowledge that if you tweaking a bit with px, you will achieve that but I am looking for more generic approach since font size will be different by cases.

Comment: And the original div entry? (just looked at your link, which really should be here) What do you mean by additional space, I do not see any?

Comment: There is a space between top of the text and top of the div

Comment: are you looking for this? https://jsfiddle.net/b6wLwkfs/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change inline text height, not just the line-height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942995/is-it-possible-to-change-inline-text-height-not-just-the-line-height)

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes I am looking for that but more of a generic way

Comment: It's going to be different for every font, as that's where the spacing is coming from.  Are you really just using the default browser font in your project?  because an answer to 'fix' this font's line-height may not be the same fix for others

Comment: @SebastianBrosch I don't think it's a duplicate

Comment: @scottohara I am using a Google Font.

Comment: @TriNguyen - so explain me the difference to the duplicate

Comment: @TriNguyen but 'what' google font...

Comment: @SebastianBrosch they asking to change inline text height by expanding text height to fit line-height. My idea is to narrow down the div to fit the text. They are opposite

Comment: @scottohara I am currently using Roboto family for it. But do we actually have generic way to deal with it?

Comment: Can anyone who is down voting my question state what is wrong with my question?

Answer (score 2):

Your code below is missing a (;) after font-size: 50px; now to achieve the space reduction I suggest you use line-height with the same font-size refer to my correction

**Your Code**

```
div {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px
}
```

**My Correction**

```
div {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: 1. The final semi-colon is a good practice, but it's not a must. 2. The line-height actually make the div get smaller in height, but doesn't eliminate the space on top and bottom

Answer (score 0):

There is likely no 'generic' way to do this, as that spacing you're seeing is actually part of the font face, and whatever adjustments you make to solve the 'problem' for this font, will not necessarily work on other fonts.

For example, just take a look at how Arial displays, as it's different than the default font that is used without setting a specific font-family, and as such a fix for the default font would likely have to be adjusted for Arial.

```css
p {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: arial;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Oh hi i'm different
</p>
```

In the above snippet I've added a line-height of 1 to help normalize the spacing a bit. You could try to adjust further with setting the line-height to be at, or close to the exact font-size in pixels, but this will likely result in undesired spacing if you have lots of text in the element (text should also be in an appropriately semantic element like a p, or li, not just in a div).

In the end, can you achieve the result you're looking for?  Definitely. Using things like line-height, margins and/or transforms.  But you are likely not going to find a silver bullet to achieve the effect you want, consistently, if swapping out font faces.

As Sebastian Brosch mentioned in the question's comments, working off from [Is it possible to change inline text height, not just the line-height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942995/is-it-possible-to-change-inline-text-height-not-just-the-line-height) is likely going to be your best path forward.